# Giving style to a css class inside of a tr tag

Tags: html, css

I currently have content which is inside of a TR tag and I'm trying to style it how ever, I'm not having very much luck.

```
<tr id="1993310">
  <td id="m1993310" class="Sent msg stxt2 u3653392 g4">
     <img src="ARTWORK" class="pic">
     <div class="dtxt2" id="t1486819648">11 Feb 17, 08:27 AM</div>
     <span class="modtools" id="mod_1993310">
        <a title="Delete" class="btnDel" href="javascript:void(0)">[×]</a>      
     </span>
     <b class="nme pn_adm">
       <span style="color:#72bc78">NAME</span>
     </b>
     : CONTENT
     </td>
  </tr>
```

If you look above you can see that there's a class called `Sent msg stxt2 u3653392 g4` I wanna change the background color to red for this user id only, and this is the only way I've found to do it how ever if I just try and put `.sent` as a class it does not do anything in terms of styles, so I'm stumped on what the actual class name would be here?

Here's another message so you can see what it looks like with a different post ID.

```
<tr id="1993309">
  <td id="m1993309" class="Sent msg stxt u3653392 g4">
     <img src="ARTWORK" class="pic">
     <div class="dtxt" id="t1486819600">11 Feb 17, 08:26 AM</div>
     <span class="modtools" id="mod_1993309">
         <a title="Delete" class="btnDel" href="javascript:void(0)">[×]</a>
     </span>
     <b class="nme pn_adm">
        <span style="color:#72bc78">NAME</span>
     </b>: CONTENT
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there's a class called `Sent msg stxt2 u3653392 g4`

Not really. You actually have five different classes

> if I just try and put `.sent` as a class it does not do anything in terms of styles

Right, because `sent` is not among your classes. However, `Sent` is:

```
.Sent{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And if you really want to style only when all five classes are present:

```
.Sent.msg.stxt2.u3653392.g4{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Now this is an answer I was looking for, thank you so much! I actually had to turn it into `.msg.stxt2.u3653392.g4` for it to work, but issue solved none the less!

Comment: `Sent.msg.stxt2.u3653392.g4` should work too (however, `sent.msg.stxt2.u3653392.g4` won't).

Answer (score 0):

As you want the background color for a particular ID,you have to give the style for that class. As per your question, `background color` should be `red` for id `m1993310`.So give the style as below

```
#m1993310
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is for the actual post id, not the actual poster ID which is in the portion I highlighted, the part we need to change has to some how be done with `class="Sent msg stxt2 u3653392 g4"` this portion. Any other method would just change the way that post displays, instead of all the post from that user.

Comment: then give a different class name for that portion

Comment: that's not an answer to the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new class `uu` for the first ID.

```
<style>
 .uu{
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<tr id="1993310">
  <td id="m1993310" class="Sent msg stxt2 u3653392 g4 uu">
     <img src="ARTWORK" class="pic">
     <div class="dtxt2" id="t1486819648">11 Feb 17, 08:27 AM</div>
     <span class="modtools" id="mod_1993310">
        <a title="Delete" class="btnDel" href="javascript:void(0)">[×]</a>      
     </span>
     <b class="nme pn_adm">
       <span style="color:#72bc78">NAME</span>
     </b>
     : CONTENT
     </td>
  </tr>

<tr id="1993309">
  <td id="m1993309" class="Sent msg stxt u3653392 g4">
     <img src="ARTWORK" class="pic">
     <div class="dtxt" id="t1486819600">11 Feb 17, 08:26 AM</div>
     <span class="modtools" id="mod_1993309">
         <a title="Delete" class="btnDel" href="javascript:void(0)">[×]</a>
     </span>
     <b class="nme pn_adm">
        <span style="color:#72bc78">NAME</span>
     </b>: CONTENT
  </td>
</tr>
```